# MVC Error: model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, partial-views, unhandled-exception

I'm doing some modifications to a system, and I've run into an exception that I was hoping someone could help with?? The error I'm getting is the following:

> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   model item passed into the dictionary
>   is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Data.aspnet_Users]'.

Basically what I want to do is display a list of Inactive users. Here is the controller I've written for that:

```
public ActionResult InactiveUsers()
        {
            using (ModelContainer ctn = new ModelContainer())
            {
                aspnet_Users users = new aspnet_Users();

                DateTime duration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);

                var inactive = from usrs in ctn.aspnet_Users
                    where usrs.LastActivityDate <= duration
                    orderby usrs.LastActivityDate ascending
                    select usrs.UserName;

                return View(inactive.ToList());
            }

        }
```

From here then I added a partial view. Here is the code for it if anyone is interested. Just the usual Add View --> List.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<MyApp.Data.aspnet_Users>>" %>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                ApplicationId
            </th>
            <th>
                UserId
            </th>
            <th>
                UserName
            </th>
            <th>
                LoweredUserName
            </th>
            <th>
                MobileAlias
            </th>
            <th>
                IsAnonymous
            </th>
            <th>
                LastActivityDate
            </th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserId }) %> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserId })%> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserId })%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.ApplicationId %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.UserId %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.UserName %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.LoweredUserName %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.MobileAlias %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.IsAnonymous %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.LastActivityDate) %>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>

    <p>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    </p>
```

And for completeness here is the Index page where I render the partial:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Administrator.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <% Html.RenderAction("InactiveUsers"); %>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

If anyone has any advice I'd be very grateful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i think its because in your partial view type is `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<MyApp.Data.aspnet_Users>>`
but you select user names

```
select usrs.UserName;

return View(inactive.ToList());
```

Try change it to select usrs; but not usrs.UserName

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks @Sanja.

Comment: @TaraWalsh no problem, just ask