# MVC4 with MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, jquery

I am currently using MVC4 in VS 2012 with MySql to built a website. I have issue when I try to display my data and get this error :

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyMvc4SalesStatistics.Models.users_internal_group_membership]'.
```

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: Hey, please show us the Controller code where you return your View(). It looks like you are passing the wrong model type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because in your view type is `System.Web.Mvc.View<IEnumerable<User-Internal-Group-MemberShip>>` but you return some other data in your controller

`return View(UserInternalGroupMemberShip.);`//Must return the your model object for view ,

But I am not sure .

Please see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313518/mvc-error-model-item-of-type-system-collections-generic-ienumerable1-required)

and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573020/mvc-error-the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-system-collect)

Comment: Thanks RameshRams It is sorted out :)